# Нужна помощь по методу Exec

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Подскажите пожалуйста почему у меня происходит цикличность!

```
var data     = document.getElementById("data").value;
var regEx = new RegExp(/(Зачаровать.{1,12}).\[(\d{1,2})\].{1,3}?(\d{1,2})?.{1,3}?([PVFERUL]+)/g);
var result = regEx.exec(data);

 while(result != null){
       alert(result);
 }

Пример потока данных в котором происходит поиск:

исп-ть
 Добавить в избранное  Выбросить предмет Зачаровать Кольцо [12]  VF   (Масса: 0.1) 
Долговечность: 0/1
Требуется минимальное:
• Уровень: 12
Действует на:
• Мф. против критического удара (%): +1
• Мф. против увертывания (%): +3
• Защита от урона: +1
• Защита от колющего урона: +1
• Защита от режущего урона: +1
• Защита от магии воздуха: +1
• Защита от магии земли: +1
• Сила: +2
• Броня головы: 3-3
• Броня ног: 1-4 (d4)
Описание:
Этим предметом можно улучшить Кольцо.
Улучшение заменит другие подобные улучшения.
Сделано в Emeralds city
Предмет не подлежит ремонту

исп-ть
 Добавить в избранное  Выбросить предмет Зачаровать Кольцо [12]  VF   (Масса: 0.1) 
Долговечность: 0/1
Требуется минимальное:
• Уровень: 12
Действует на:
• Мф. против критического удара (%): +2
• Мф. против увертывания (%): +1
• Ловкость: +2
• Защита от магии: +3
• Защита от магии огня: +1
• Броня ног: 1-8 (d8)
Описание:
Этим предметом можно улучшить Кольцо.
Улучшение заменит другие подобные улучшения.
Сделано в Emeralds city
Предмет не подлежит ремонту

исп-ть
 Добавить в избранное  Выбросить предмет Зачаровать Кольцо [12]  P   (Масса: 0.1) 
Долговечность: 0/1
Требуется минимальное:
• Уровень: 12
Действует на:
• Мф. против критического удара (%): +1
• Защита от рубящего урона: +1
• Защита от режущего урона: +1
• Защита от магии воды: +1
• Защита от магии воздуха: +1
• Броня головы: 1-1 (d1)
• Броня корпуса: 1-1
• Броня пояса: 1-1 (d1)
Описание:
Этим предметом можно улучшить Кольцо.
Улучшение заменит другие подобные улучшения.
Сделано в Abandoned Plain
Предмет не подлежит ремонту

исп-ть
 Добавить в избранное  Выбросить предмет Зачаровать Кольцо [12]  P   (Масса: 0.1) 
Долговечность: 0/1
Требуется минимальное:
• Уровень: 12
Действует на:
• Мф. против критического удара (%): +2
• Мф. против увертывания (%): +1
• Защита от режущего урона: +1
• Уровень маны: +1
• Броня головы: 1-1
• Броня ног: 1-2 (d2)
Описание:
Этим предметом можно улучшить Кольцо.
Улучшение заменит другие подобные улучшения.
Сделано в Abandoned Plain
Предмет не подлежит ремонту
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перепишите так:

```
while (result= regex.exec(data)) {
    alert(result);
}
```

У Вас происходит бесконечный цикл так как Вы не изменяете result, но проверяете его на null.

Comment: Спасибо большое,теперь все понял!